# Will block chain pruning work for zeronet (Website hosting on block chain)?

Tags: blockchain, pruning

Pruning limits block chain by removing old blocks. Will this methodology work for zeronet. One of the perks of zeronet is to be able to access websites (read zites) even without internet connectivity.

So, if your answer is YES. please explain the above scenario as well.

Thanks in advance.